# The !address windbg command says that heap address is 'REGionUsageIsVAD' even though it was allocated using HeapAlloc

Tags: debugging, windbg

My heap buffer of interest was allocated as follows:

```
0:047> !heap -p -a 1d7cd1f0
    address 1d7cd1f0 found in
    _DPH_HEAP_ROOT @ 5251000
    in busy allocation (  DPH_HEAP_BLOCK:         UserAddr         UserSize -         VirtAddr         VirtSize)
                                1cf8f5b0:         1d7cc008             3ff8 -         1d7cb000             6000
    68448e89 verifier!AVrfDebugPageHeapAllocate+0x00000229
    76e465ee ntdll!RtlDebugAllocateHeap+0x00000030
    76e0a793 ntdll!RtlpAllocateHeap+0x000000c4
    76dd5dd0 ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0x0000023a
    000ca342 TEST+0x0002a342
    000be639 TEST+0x0001e639
```

As you can see, it was allocated using HeapAlloc(). When I run the `!address` command on the pointer of this heap I get:

```
 ProcessParametrs 01699928 in range 01699000 0169a000
 Environment 016976e8 in range 01697000 01698000
    1d790000 : 1d7cb000 - 00005000
                    Type     00020000 MEM_PRIVATE
                    Protect  00000004 PAGE_READWRITE
                    State    00001000 MEM_COMMIT
                    Usage    RegionUsageIsVAD
```

It claims to be in `RegionUsageIsVAD`. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032482/viewing-the-actual-data-in-address-regionusageisvad-windbg) stackoverflow answer, `RegionUsageIsVAD` generally means two things:

1. This is a .NET application in which case, the CLR allocates this
   block of memory.
2. The application calls VirtualAlloc to allocate a
   bloc of memory.

My scenario does not fit either one of these cases. I confirmed that CLR wasn't used by running `.cordll -ve -u -l` to which I got:

```
CLR DLL status: No load attempts
```

What does `RegionUsageIsVAD` mean in this case?

Comment: "My **heap** of interest has the following allocation **stack** trace" - Heap and stack are very different memory allocation mechanisms. A heap does not have a stack trace (actually a stack also has none). What do you mean?

Comment: By "allocation stack trace" I  meant that is what the stack trace was when the heap buffer  was allocated. You can use the `!heap -p -a` command in windbg to see this stack trace.

Comment: Iirc There is some limit in size after which heapalloc uses virtual alloc maybe you hit the limit ill update if i find my old posts

Comment: `1d7cd1f0` is not in that range.

Comment: I think @blabb is really close. Notice the `verifier!AVrfDebugPageHeapAllocate` frame on the stack? `PageHeap` is turned on for this process which will circumvent the typical heap allocation scheme and go straight to `VirtualAlloc`.

Comment: @blabb: the limit is 512k according to Sasha Goldshtein: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2015/10/23/large-win32-heap-allocations-go-directly-to-virtualalloc/ and in that case it would not have a user stack trace associated

Comment: This seems to be a test application. Would you mind posting the source?

Answer (score 0):

i reread your question thinking i would update what i commented
but upon   closer look it seems there are lot of holes
it appears you copied things and didnt paste right
where is that pointer on heap ?
01699928  which version of windbg are you using
since i couldn't confirm i cooked up a simple program 
enabled hpa in gflags and executed the exe under windbg 
below is the screen shot
except what you paste as isregionvad ( this line is output under kernel !address not in user !address ) every thing else appears to be similar in the screenshot

[image]